# PHP Regex is not working properly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have a variable that can receive these two values:

'**01838723001603 TELO 155**' ou '**01838723009850 0608**'.

I want to get the second value after the number of 14 characters.
For that, I'm trying the following regular expression, but it is not working:

```
/[0-9]{14} (.*?)/i
```

---

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{14} (.*?)/i', $data, $result);
var_dump($result);
```

**Result -> [0 => '01838723026436', 1 => '01838723026436'].**

She's just taking the first value (01838723001603).
**I want her to return values: 'TELO 155' / '0608'**

(this has to be done using regular expression, because these data are being captured from a text file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try look behinds as

```
/?<=\d{14}\s)[^']+/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rK4mJ5/1)

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=\\d{14}\\s)[^']+/", "01838723001603 TELO 155' ou '01838723009850 0608'.", $matches);
```

will give output as

```
Array ( [0] => Array 
                 ( [0] => TELO 155 
                   [1] => 0608 ) 
      )
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $data = "01838723009850 0608";  //01838723001603 TELO 155
    preg_match_all('/\d{14}\s?(.*?)$/', $data, $result);
    echo $result[1][0];

?>
```

Output:

```
0608  //TELO 155
```